# Android Studio can't find imported library

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

I've imported a library in Android studio (0.5.3)

My settings.graddle looks like this:

```
include ':app', ':libs:Android-PullToRefresh-master'
```

And my build.graddle looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    project(':libs:Android-PullToRefresh-master');
}
```

The folder I've downloaded is placed in the libs folder directly under the app folder. Also the graddle syncs and building doesn't provide any error. Yet whenever I try to import `import com.handmark.xxxxxx;` I get the error `cannot resolve symbol 'handmark'`. I've chcecked to project structure and the app has the dependency in the list.

What is going wrong and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue here and [asked the question](https://plus.google.com/u/0/104567775398355774153/posts/Rz19RRyewpR) on the "Android Developer Tools" Google+'s community. Alex Ruiz picked up the conversation and told me:

> I'm able to reproduce this issue. Unfortunately, no updates yet. We
>   are currently fixing the "Project Structure" (the core
>   infrastructure,) and we will get to this, hopefully soon.

So they are aware of it but we still have to wait until they fix it.

Comment: In other words, it's broken at the moment?

Comment: Yes indeed, it's broken.

Answer (score 2):

In the root of your project, run :

```
./gradlew clean && ./gradlew build
```

Then recompile your project in studio and you should see your new lib.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem as this, however the library file was an aar file, and it happened a long time after adding the library and developing with it for a while.

Building on the information **Thomas** [provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22861076/1354282); I found to fix this you should replace the file dependency with a maven dependency if possible. A good resource for finding and creating your Gradle dependency is [Gradle, please](http://gradleplease.appspot.com/).

That site returns the below dependency when searching for `PullToRefresh`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.loopeer.android.thirdparty.pulltorefresh:Android-PullToRefresh:2.1.1'
}
```