# Android Studio won't detect my library components despite having the library added as a dependency

Tags: java, android

I have made a simple project where I have created a new module called 'mylibrary' & it has a Custom view in it.

The library was automatically added to the list of dependencies in the project during the time of its creation.

However, the app that depends on this library cannot find a Custom view existing within the library.

I have tried several suggestions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588389/android-libraries-in-android-studio), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29188361/android-studio-does-not-recognize-libraries) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22860553/android-studio-cant-find-imported-library), but none of them worked.

I have listed the required files below: -

**build.gradle(Module:mylibrary)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**build.gradle (Project: TESTAPP)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle (Module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.auro.self.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile project(':mylibrary')
}
```

**settings.gradle (Project Settings)**

```
include ':app', ':mylibrary'
```

**mylibrary --> samplelayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:hint="HEY"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</merge>
```

**mylibrary --> CustomView.java**

```
package app.auro.self.mylibrary;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import java.security.PrivateKey;

/**
 * Created by stpl on 25/8/16.
 */
public class CustomView extends LinearLayout {

    private EditText editText;

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        this(context,null);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs,0);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        inflater.inflate(R.layout.samplelayout,this,true);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText.setText("HELLO");
    }
}
```

**app --> activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="app.auro.self.testapp.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Cus //DOESN'T EVEN DETECT

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**app --> MainActivity.java**

```
package app.auro.self.testapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import app.auro.self.mylibrary.CustomView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CustomView customView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your layout xml files, only the classes within the `android.widget` package can be used with their name directly. Everything else needs to be declared with their fully qualified class name. For eg:

```
<!-- Won't work -->
<CardView.../> 

<!-- Should work -->
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView.../>
```

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, but when you start typing something like `<CircleImage...`, a list of suggestions comes up on the right side with the full package name. Its name should show up in the suggestion if the library, whose content the view is, is added as a dependency to the project. I have tried writing the entire name as well, shows error saying `component cannot be found`. However, in my `MainActivity` , when I start typing `CustomView`, it automatically shows up

Comment: @Auro Alright, that means the library is integrated properly. If you can create a bare bones stub project which can reproduce the issue, you should submit it on AS Issue Tracker: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Android%20Studio%20bug

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue , you can try using your layout/class in your main activity and from there copy the import and paste it in your layout and then it should detect your custom layout without any troubles

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31750159)